# Sending text to comment to PHP site using Objective-C

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I want to sent comment in controller to PHP site.

The following is my code for doing that:

```
NSString *word = _commentText.text;
NSString *user =[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
NSSTring *post = 500 //webpage content site 
if(word !=nil){
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Finished" message:@"Comment Finished" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    //NSString *filenames=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TextLabel"];
    NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"id=%@&no=%@&comment=%@",user,code,word];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [postString UTF8String] length: [postString length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mylink.com/comment_upload2.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSLog(@"%@",_commentText.text);
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];

    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"%@", request);
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    NSData *retunData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
     NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:retunData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     NSLog(returnString);
     NSLog(@"Commented");

}//if
```

But when I touch on the comment, the comment does not appear in my site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your php code get the data after you send the request. Something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'] && isset($_POST['no'] && isset($_POST['comment']) {
  // log data here
}
```

Then return the data in json format using json_encode() function so you'll know that you get the data right. You can use the code below to perform the request.

```
    NSString *post       =  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"id=%@&no=%@&comment=%@",user,code,word];
    NSData *postData     =  [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *postLength =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSString * urlstring =  [YOUR_API_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url                      =   [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request    =   [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod              =   @"POST";
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if(connectionError) {
             NSLog(@"Connection Error:\n%@",connectionError.description);
         } else {
             NSDictionary* responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
             NSLog(@"responseDictionary : %@", responseDictionary);
         }
     }];
```

Comment: I use it null value. in YOUR_API_URL I use mylink.com/comment_upload2.php it true?

Comment: What do you mean "I use it null value"? and yes, YOUR_API_URL is your current API... Remember that to solve your problem in displaying the comment from objective-c to your site, your PHP code must be correct in getting the right data. Your objective-c code here only passes the data.

Comment: log in responseDictionary's print blank